# What is the vulnerability of this code snippet?

Tags: php, mysql

```php
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username =? AND password = ? ")

$stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password)

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: This seems ok, but don't use `SELECT *`. Instead, always name (and qualify) the columns you want returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be no vulnerability in your code snippet, at least not from the point of SQL injection.  However, I see another problem, which is that it appears you are storing clear text passwords into your `login` table.  Instead, consider following the safer pattern of first hashing the user passwords with a salt, and then storing this hashed value in the table.  Then, when a user does a login, you would again hash the incoming password to compare against what is stored in the `login` table.  This avoids the risk of someone malicious accidentally getting access to every user password.

Comment: So, to reiterate, you are using statements, which in theory should mean zero chance of SQL injection, but you might want to rethink your table structure.